# How to update bokeh active interaction with GeoJSON as data source?

Tags: drop-down-menu, bokeh, geojson

I have made an interactive choropleth map with bokeh, and I'm trying to add active interactions using the dropdown widget (Select). However, most tutorials and SO questions about active interactions use ColumnDataSource, and not GeoJSONDataSource.

The issue is that GeoJSONDataSource doesn't have a .data method like ColumnDataSource does, so idk exactly how the syntax works when updating it.

My dataset is a dictionary in the form of `city_dict = {'Amsterdam': <some data frame>, 'Antwerp': <some data frame>, ...}`, where the dataframe is in geojson format. I have already confirmed that this format works when making glyphs.

```
def update(attr, old, new):

    s_value = dropdown.value
    p.title.text = '%s', s_value

    new_src1 = make_dataset(s_value)

    val1 = GeoJSONDataSource(new_src1)

    r1.data_source = val1
```

where `make_dataset` is a function that transforms my original dataset into a dataset that can feed into the GeoJSONDataSource function. `make_dataset` requires a string (name of the city) to work eg. 'Amsterdam'. It works on passive interactions.

The main plot code (removed unnecessary stuff) is:

```
dropdown = Select(value='Amsterdam', options = cities)
controls = WidgetBox(dropdown)
initial_city = 'Amsterdam'
a = make_dataset(initial_city)
src1 = GeoJSONDataSource(a)

p = figure(title = 'Amsterdam', plot_height = 750 , plot_width = 900, toolbar_location = 'right')

r1 = p.patches('xs','ys', source = src1, fill_color = {'field' :'norm', 'transform' : color_mapper})

dropdown.on_change('value', update)
layout = row(controls, p)
curdoc().add_root(layout)
```

I've added the error I get. `error handling message Message 'PATCH-DOC' (revision 1) content: {'events': [{'kind': 'ModelChanged', 'model': {'type': 'Select', 'id': '1147'}, 'attr': 'value', 'new': 'Antwerp'}], 'references': []}: ValueError("expected a value of type str, got ('%s', 'Antwerp') of type tuple",)`

Comment: It would be better if you post a minimal but complete and runnable code